# How to get a list from a file, compare it with 2nd list, deduplicate and save new records back in to the file?

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io

I have a follow code which works nice while both lists are defined in the code:

```
dataOld = ['apples', 'pineapple']

dataNew = ['apples', 'pineapple', 'avocado']

for data in dataNew:
    if data not in dataOld:
        dataUpdated = dataOld.append(data)
```

Now I would like to change the source for `dataOld` to the external file. Below described update doesn't work. I probably did some beginner's mistake somewhere, but I don't know where?

```
import os

if os.path.exists('testfile.txt'):
    dataFile = open('testfile.txt', 'r')
    dataOld = dataFile.readlines()

    for line in dataOld:
        lineUpdated = line.rstrip("\n")

else:
   dataFile = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
   dataOld = set()

dataNew = ['apples', 'pineapple', 'avocado']

for data in dataNew:
   if data not in dataOld:
       dataUpdated = dataOld.append(data)
       dataFile.write(str(data+"\n"))   
dataFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to change the list in the for loop here:

```
 for line in dataOld:
     lineUpdated = line.rstrip("\n")
```

This will assign something to `lineUpdated` but not change the value in `dataOld`.

Try a list comprehension and an assignment:

```
dataOld = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in dataOld]
```

Also try working with `set`:

```
dataNew = set(['apples', 'pineapple', 'avocado'])
dataOld = set(line.rstrip("\n") for line in dataOld)
dataUpdated = dataNew - dataOld
```

Your file handling also needs reworking, you cannot write to a file opened for reading. Try to use the `with` statement:

```
if os.path.exists('testfile.txt'):
    with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as dataFile:
        dataOld = dataFile.readlines()
else:
    dataOld=set()
...
with open('testfile.txt', 'a') as dataFile:
    for data in dataUpdated:
        dataFile.write(str(data)+"\n")
```

Comment: Why not directly read the data from the file instead: `dataOld = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in dataFile` or even `dataOld = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in open('testfile.txt', 'r')` which is more pythonic.`

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, I tried your suggested update, but I ended up with solution that will add only newly added record from `dataNew` in to the file. Previous content of the file is deleted. Could you please be more specific what part of the original code is needed to rework and how? Thank you

Comment: @user2726562 Change the mode of the file to `'a'` when writing: this will append to the file, rather than deleting it before writing: `open('testfile.txt', 'a')`

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny Works like a charm. Thank you! :-)